# bokeh click a drawn circle on a gmap plot

Tags: bokeh

I am using bokeh server and using the gmap component and displaying some circles on it using the `GeoJsonDataSource` to fill the location data.

So, I have something as:

```
map_options = GMapOptions()
map_options.map_type = 'roadmap'
map_options.zoom = 12
map_options.lat = -1.5
map_options.lng = 50.0
map_source = GeoJSONDataSource() 
hover = HoverTool()
hover.tooltips = [('Location', '@x, @y')]

# I can create the map and draw circles and hover on the circles as follows:
map = gmap(api_key, map_options)
map.circle(x="x", y="y", size=15, source=map_source)
map.add_tools(hover)

# to make the circle clckable
map.add_tools(TapTool())

# try and make a callback 
def callback(attr, old, new):
   # Somehow I need to get the actual underlying data which generated this circle element in the map_source
   print(">")

map_source.on_change('indices', callback)
# The line above gives an error
#  ValueError("attempted to add a callback on nonexistent %s.%s 
#  property" % (self.__class__.__name__, attr))

# Doing the following has no effect
map_source.on_change('selected', callback)
```

This works fine and I can see my circle and can hover over it to display the location. Also, the TapTool works as expected. So, I can click on a circle and the rest fade into the background. But I have no clue how I can get the index of the currently selected circle.

Comment: You need to share the actual code for the things you have tried to do to make the circle clickable.

Comment: @bigreddot Added some more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
map_source.selected.on_change('indices', callback)
```

Comment: Oh great! Thanks, this works but I am confused now...Is there any way to go from this selection index, which I guess is what is encapsulated in the `new` parameter to the actual object/data in the `map_source`?

Comment: `new` is the new value of `map_source.selected.indices`. Alternatively, you can just access `map_source.selected.indices` directly from inside the callback since it is in the enclosing module scope.